# How do I get the email addresses of multiple recipients from a PayPal IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using the Parrallel payment feature of the Adaptive Payment API. In some cases, I have more than one recipient.

Reading the paypal [reference on IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNReference) , there's no way to get more than one recipient email address. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adaptive Payments reference on [this page](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIPN) says:

> transaction[n].receiver  :    The receiver’s email address for the transaction

where "n" should be the number of recipients, larger than 0 in parallel payments.

**--UPDATE:**

OK. The problem is that Paypal is sending an array within an array through POST. In PHP, $_POST shows an "Array", but it can't be read. I got a workaround to read the response:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
mail("my@email.com", "IPN response", $postdata);
```

it isn't a clean solution, but it works. Improvements are welcome ;)

Comment: I just tried out a chained payment in PHP (which is similar to parallel in the response) and I can't read those fields. Strange...

Comment: oh, feel silly for missing that. I'll test it out and see what happens.